# Why is the Spring OAuth2 authorization endpoint protected?

Tags: spring, oauth-2.0

Why is the Spring OAuth2 authorization endpoint protected and only accessible to authenticated users, as described under "Configuring the endpoint URLs" [here](http://projects.spring.io/spring-security-oauth/1.x/docs/oauth2.html)?

Following my understanding of the OAuth2 authorization code grant, a call to the authorization endpoint should return a dialog, where the user enters his credentials in order to be authenticated or am I wrong? The authenticated user can later retrieve an access token from the token endpoint (which is not protected according to the description above).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The authorization endpoint is typically a dialog where the user **authorizes** the requesting system to perform requests on his behalf to the target system.

Before this can happen, he needs to be **authenticated** in the target system, which means that the authorization endpoint must be secured.

Since it is secured, the user will automatically be redirected to a login page, and after successful login he will be forwarded to the actual authorization endpoint where he can accept the authorization request.

After completed authorization, the user will be redirected back to the requesting system, which will then perform a back-channel request for a token. This back-channel request includes a code parameter (provided in the final redirect), verifying that the token request is indeed on behalf of the user.

Comment: Arn't there two authorize endpoints though? One is a GET  which verifies your client_id and other parameters, which forwards you to a secured consent form. Once the consent form is confirmed, the login server uses the other authorize endpoint (with POST) go validate the authorization and get the code. The POST /authorize would be protected and should only be accepted from the login app.
I'm looking at the [rfc](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc6749#section-4.1) and [apigee](https://docs.apigee.com/api-platform/security/oauth/oauth-v2-policy-authorization-code-grant-type)